# Handle keyevent in custom AutoCompleteTextview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, keyevent

I was creating `CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` and i want to handle key event (any button press) but i don't want to use `Textwatcher` (etc `addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()`). 
How i can to detect key event by another method ? like (`onKeydown`) , but for all buttons. is it possible ?

Comment: you dont need it (in fact you dont need TextWatcher as well), all you need is an adapter that implements `Filterable` interface

Comment: also read `KeyEvent` docs: """As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event: [...], and in fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular, the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier"""

Comment: As i said, you dont need any `TextWatcher`, where does your data come from? web interface, local sqlite db?

Comment: `AutoCompleteTextView` without the adapter? it will not work, sorry...

Comment: so you have to call `setAdapter`, and use the adapter that implements `Filterable` intarface, where does your data come from? web interface, local sqlite db?

Comment: so what is your problem really? where does your data come from? web interface, local sqlite db?

Comment: finally... so use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and setup its `FilterQueryProvider`, that's all, no need for any custom `ACTV`

Comment: and in practice it works like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830)

Comment: of course you dont need to use `MatrixCursor` but directly call `SQLiteDatabase#query` / `SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery` to return the `Cursor`